# compare and replace in data frame

Tags: r

I'm new with R, so not sure how to program with R
I have 2 data frames, the first one (tst_dp) I have assigned numeric values depending on the string value of the Ac1CodSinDuplicados column

```
   Ac1CodSinDuplicados valor
                  ESP     1
               FRAOPP     2
                  BUS     3
                  USA     4
                  DEU     5
               ESPGOV     6
                  GOV     7
               ESPCVL     8
```

...

And I have a second data frame

```
> ds2
   Actor1Code Actor2Code
     ESP     BUS
```

I want to search in the first data frame and assign the numeric value in the second,for example, for every ESP, assign value 1, etc..

The final result will be a dataframe of only numeric values
Actor1Code Actor2Code
       1        3

Comment: Read `help("merge")`.

Comment: I need to replace values not to merge

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.